# Angular 4 direct download images

Tags: angular

In my angular 4 application I have a gallery with some thumbnails, every thumbnails have a download button.

I want to start the download of the image when this button is clicked, is it possible in angular?

Now when I click in the button I have:

**component.ts**

```
  downloadImage(downloadLink) {

    this.mediaService.getImage(downloadLink).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(res);
        window.open(fileURL);
      }
    );
  }
```

And in the service:

```
  getImage(imageUrl: string) {
    return this.http.get(imageUrl, {observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob'})
      .map((res) => {
        return new Blob([res.body], {type: res.headers.get('Content-Type')});
      })
  }
```

But obviously `window.open(fileURL)` opens a new window with the image.

Comment: I would recommend to use filesaver.js for that. I have described the procedure here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871600/download-file-sent-in-response-angular2/44879029#44879029

Comment: Is it possible without intalling anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I use this method:

```
this.mediaService.getImage(downloadLink).subscribe(
  (res) => {
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = URL.createObjectURL(res);
        a.download = title;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
  });
}
```

Comment: if i pass directly image url on that i got error:Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided

Answer (score 1):

To direcly download the image you can try with :

```
downloadImage(downloadLink) {

this.mediaService.getImage(downloadLink).subscribe(
  (res) => {
    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(res);
    window.location.href = fileUrl;
  }
);
}
```

Comment: It opens the image in the current tab, but I want to direct open the SaveAs dialog

Comment: i got error:Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided