# Angular 5 How to download a remote image

Tags: angular, angular5

In Angular 5, I want to download an image from localhost (server). I already have the image name with the path as: http://localhost/projectName/uploads/3/1535352341_download.png 
Now I want to download by clicking on a button.

In the HTML view in Angular, I wrote the following code:

```
<button (click)="downloadImage(car.carItem.carTitle)" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info btn-action" tooltip="Download Image" placement="left" container="body"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

In the .ts file, I do the following but it opens the image in the same tab:

```
downloadImage(imagePath){
  window.location = imagePath;
}
```

I have already gone through the post [Angular 4 direct download images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47431331/angular-4-direct-download-images?noredirect=1&lq=1) but unable to find any solution. So please don't mark it as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href=" http://localhost/projectName/uploads/3/1535352341_download.png" class="btn clss"
                  target="_self" download>Download</a>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: The solution doesn't even work, it just opens the image on the browser in the same tab.

Answer (score 5):

Since your image is on a remote server, you can't download it simply as you would with your own ressources for security reasons.

This what a simple downloadUrl function looks like, It will ask the browser to download any given url:

```js
    function downloadUrl(url: string, fileName: string) {
      const a: any = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = url;
      a.download = fileName;
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.style = 'display: none';
      a.click();
      a.remove();
    };
```

Since we can't download remote ressources, we will have to built it client-side.
We will fetch the resource and create its own url. Then we will finally be able to download it using our `downloadUrl` function.

```js
    constructor(
      private http: HttpClient,
    ) { }

-------
    this.http.get(urlImage, { responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe(val => {
      console.log(val);
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(val);
      downloadUrl(url, 'image.png');
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    });
```

Comment: Its opening the image in the same tab!

Comment: What do you mean by 'open in the same tab'. You asked to download it, not open it.

Comment: I mean your code opening the image in the same tab. I want to download it.

Comment: Also, this image is in another server (CORS).

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the problem.

Comment: Obviously. In Ng, nobody wants to store image as its use for UI purpose. Developers generally do store the images in server side like PHP and get the details from there and download the same via UI.  Sorry, can't get the answer yet.

Comment: Ok, I just found a solution, let we write it.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly: "How to download a remote image"

Comment: Last info, I added `URL.revokeObjectURL(url);` statement to prevent memory leaks. Also, don't forget to accept the answer if it fits your needs.

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: That is a problem from your back-end, it's another question. You need to allow your application to do cross origin request to your images.

Comment: I am agree with @Ploppy that this is then problem from server-side to handle such requirement, said purpose or intention is to just clear the approach for other developers those are trying to give the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
  constructor(private rs: RequestService,
      private http: Http,
      private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  getImage(imageUrl: string) {
      return this.http
                 .get(imageUrl, {responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob})
                 .map((res) => {
                     return new Blob([res.blob()], {type: res.headers.get('Content-Type')});
                 });
  }

  downloadImage(downloadLink) {
      this.orderService
          .getImage(downloadLink)
          .subscribe(
              (res) => {
                  const a = document.createElement('a');
                  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(res);
                  a.download = 'comprobante';
                  document.body.appendChild(a);
                  a.click();
              });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Ploppy for leading me in the right direction,

Here is my solution, with using fetch (TypeScript) and bypassing cors

```
const getExternalImageFromURL = (requesturl: string): Promise<Blob> => {
    const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";

    return fetch(proxyurl + requesturl).then((res) => {
        return res.blob();
    });
};
```

Comment: re Blob ;)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have requirement to do CORS in your application then at server side there must be some mechanism to allow ONLY specified cross site request, so below snippet is for NodeJs

```
let middle_ware = (req, res, next) => next();
...
return function (req, res, next) {
    const allowed_Origins = ['http://any_url.com'];
    const origin = req.headers.origin;
    if (allowed_Origins.includes(origin)) {
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
    }
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.header({
      HttpOnly: true,
      Secure: true,
      SameSite: 'None',
    });
    middle_ware(req, res, next);
  };
```

and if you were using PHP, I hope in PHP this might help you [Cross-Origin Request Headers(CORS) with PHP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cross-origin-request-headerscors-with-php-headers)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I used SaveAs to download image from unsplash .

Step1. Installation

npm i angular-file-saver

Step2. Import this into your component
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver/FileSaver';

Step3. Call a function with image url as argument

```
download(url){
    this.http.get(url,{ responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe(
      (d:any)=>{
        console.log("image url data",d);
        saveAs(d, "image.jpg");
    
      },
      (err:any)=>{
        console.log("error",err)
      }
    )
  
  }
```